# Show or hide div when URL contains certain section of text

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
    <script>
if (/en/.test(window.location.href)) {
  document.getElementById('slogannederlands').style.display = 'none';
}

    if (/nl/.test(window.location.href)) {
  document.getElementById('sloganenglish').style.display = 'none';
}

</script>
```

Depending if the URL **ends** with    /en/    or    /nl/    it will not display a certain div. It is also possible to make it so that if it shows    /en/ or /nl/    **ANYWHERE** in the URL that it will perform the same action?

Thanks, Eddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use split, which will create an array, and if the array length is greater than 1, the search string exists.

```
var url = window.location.href
if(url.split('/en/').length > 1) {
   //success
}
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/5ywghLtj/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexOf:

```
var url = window.location.href;

if (url.indexOf("/en/") > -1)
{
    document.getElementById('slogannederlands').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('sloganenglish').style.display = 'true';
}

else if (url.indexOf("/nl/") > -1)
{
    document.getElementById('sloganenglish').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('slogannederlands').style.display = 'true';
}
```

[`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/indexOf) returns the position of the string in the other string. If not found, it will return -1

So it doesn't matter at what position in the url `/en/` or `/nl/` will be.